# java Comparators for a class in another class

Tags: java, class, comparator

Given three classes X, Y and Z in Java.

In X I have a public nonstatic function "double distance(Y)".
In Z I have an object x of type X and an Array.
How could I sort the array in ascending order of distance()'s from x?

I am trying to find a solution using a comparator for Y but I have to admit I am clueless. Thank you!

**Edit**: I still get an error I could not find more about. Based on the solution in the answer, my code looks like this now:

```
public SARAgent(PathBandit game, int n) {
  ...
  Arrays.sort(getEdgeSet(game).toArray(), BY_GAP);
}

public static Comparator<Edge> BY_GAP = new Comparator<Edge>() {
  public int compare(Edge a, Edge b) {
    double va = game.delta(a.getX(), a.getY(), a.getDir());
    double vb = game.delta(b.getX(), b.getY(), b.getDir());
    if (va == vb) return a.compareTo(b);
    if (va < vb)  return -1;
    if (va > vb)  return +1;
    return 0;
  }
};
```

Edges are Comparable, yet the code doesn't compile, with an error on the call to Arrays.sort(). The error is

```
Error: no suitable method found for sort(java.lang.Object[],java.util.Comparator<Edge>)
method java.util.Arrays.<T>sort(T[],int,int,java.util.Comparator<? super T>) is not applicable
  (cannot instantiate from arguments because actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method java.util.Arrays.<T>sort(T[],java.util.Comparator<? super T>) is not applicable
  (actual argument java.util.Comparator<Edge> cannot be converted to java.util.Comparator<? super java.lang.Object> by method invocation conversion)
method java.util.Arrays.sort(java.lang.Object[],int,int) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method java.util.Arrays.sort(java.lang.Object[]) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method java.util.Arrays.sort(double[],int,int) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method java.util.Arrays.sort(double[]) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method java.util.Arrays.sort(float[],int,int) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method java.util.Arrays.sort(float[]) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method java.util.Arrays.sort(byte[],int,int) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method java.util.Arrays.sort(byte[]) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method java.util.Arrays.sort(char[],int,int) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method java.util.Arrays.sort(char[]) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method java.util.Arrays.sort(short[],int,int) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method java.util.Arrays.sort(short[]) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method java.util.Arrays.sort(long[],int,int) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method java.util.Arrays.sort(long[]) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method java.util.Arrays.sort(int[],int,int) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method java.util.Arrays.sort(int[]) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Comment: Description ok..where is the code ??

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize I should post code. The question was simple, and the code was confused and probably conceptually wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Z` you can create a Comparator that looks something like this:

```
public static Comparator<Y> cmp = new Comparator<Y>() {
    public int compare(Y y1, Y y2) {
        return (int) Math.signum(x.distance(y1) - x.distance(y2));
    }
};
```

You can then use this comparator to sort your array:

```
Arrays.sort(arrayOfY, cmp);
```

Comment: distance returns double, compare returns int, you will get type mismatch

Comment: +1 for editing, and btw you don't need to do any math there, you can do Double.compare(x.distance(y1), x.distance(y2))